# regex string between two characters from end php

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to get a part of string doing regex.
For eg.

```
$input = "This is a 'wonderful' day except i am 'stuck' here"
```

I want to get all characters between two `'`s.

for this i'm using

```
preg_match('~\'(.*?)\'~', $input, $output);
```

but the result i'm getting is only `wonderful` in `$output[0]`

what i'm doing wrong? how to get the second part i.e. `stuck` in this example?

EDIT:
I asked this question after checking $output[1]. '`stuck`' is not there!

also apart from testing it from my program, i also tried an online regex tester. here's the result:

http://s30.postimg.org/g6dj5xvmp/Selection_009.png

Comment: Kind'a guessing here (never used php), but I think your version will work if you just add the global flag after the last '~', i.e. `~\'(.*?)\'~g` and remove the last ')' which I guess was a typo (or it wouldn't have worked at all). (Also, escaping the ' aren't necessary.)

Comment: hey thanks for pointing out ')' was a typo..

Comment: @ClasG: the single quotes _have_ to be escaped here, because the OP's pattern string is delimited by single quotes... and PHP's implementation of the PCRE doesn't have a global flag, but there is a `preg_match_all` function which does the same thing

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: OK, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really quite simple. You're using `preg_match`, which attempts to find *one* occurance of a given pattern, to find all matches [use `preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all).
Both work in the same way: the `$matches` array will have *the full pattern-match* assigned to index 0 (including the quotes), and the group(s) will be assigned to all subsequent indexes (in this case `$matches[0]` will contain the chars inside the quotes). The difference is that `preg_match_all` will assign *arrays* to the aforementioned indexes, listing each match for the pattern.

```
preg_match("/'([^]+)'/", $input, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

will give an array like this:

```
array(
    "'wonderful'",    //because the pattern mentions the ' chars
    "wonderful"       //because I'm grouping the chars inside the '
);
```

Whereas this code:

```
preg_match_all("/'([^']+)'/", $input, $matches));
```

Gives you:

```
array (
   //array of full matches, including the quotes
   array (
       '\'wonderful\'',
       '\'stuck\'',
   ),
   //array with groups
   array (
       'wonderful',
       'stuck',
   ),
);
```

As you can see [***on this live example***](https://eval.in/91068)

I've simplified your expression a little, because you're interested in what's *"delimited"* by single quotes, hence I match and group every non `'` that follows a single quote and that is, in turn followed by another single quote. Thus, the char-class you want to match is simply `[^']`... anything except `'`.
A possiple micro-optimization you could make to this suggested pattern would be to use a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `++`, which is similar to `{1,}`. Or, if you want to match an empty string if `''` is found, you could use `*+`. so

```
if (preg_match_all("/'([^']++)'/", $subject, $matches))
    var_dump($matches);
```

Should do the trick

Comment: @singhshivam: Yes... I explained why `preg_match` doesn't match all occurances of a given patter, and that is why you should use `preg_match_all`. I also suggested changing your pattern a little, because as it now stands `this '' string` will leave you with an empty match

Comment: thanks Elias i got it. your answer should have worked for me first time itself but i made some stupid mistake. Anyways thanks a lot for explaining me in such details! :)

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
<?php
$str = "This is a 'wonderful' day except i am 'stuck' here";
preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => wonderful
    [1] => stuck
)
```

Comment: @singhshivam, What is your expected `output` ? I don't see any difference in the question btw. See the **demo** https://eval.in/91036

Comment: its strange, its working fine on eval, even my complete code shows the correct result. But not working on my program.
anyways im sure now the problem here. Thanks a lot for your help! :)